# How to check if a home screen short-cut exists or not?

Tags: android, homescreen, installed-applications

Is there a way to determine whether a particular home screen shortcut 
exists?  Or is there a way to stop the Toast messages that appear 
when a home screen shortcut is installed and uninstalled?

My application installs a shortcut on the home screen at device 
startup time under certain conditions and I don't want duplicate 
shortcuts to appear. I also don't want Toast messages appearing saying 
"Shortcut created" or "Shortcut already exists" every single time the 
device boots. Is there any solution to stop these Toast messages?

Thanks

Comment: Why should an app install / unistall shortcuts on every reboot? That seems pretty unusual behavior to me. Could you explain your use-case a bit more :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should not install on device reboot. use the following code:

```
public void createOrUpdateShortcut() {

    appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    isAppInstalled = appPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled", false);

    String currentLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
    String previousSetLanguage = appPreferences.getString("phoneLanguage", Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());

    if (!previousSetLanguage.equals(currentLanguage)) {
        shortcutReinstall = true;
    }

     if(!isAppInstalled || shortcutReinstall){

        Intent HomeScreenShortCut= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                BrowserLauncherActivity.class);

        HomeScreenShortCut.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        HomeScreenShortCut.putExtra("duplicate", false);

        if(shortcutReinstall) {
            Intent removeIntent = new Intent();
            removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, HomeScreenShortCut);
            String prevAppName = appPreferences.getString("appName", getString(R.string.app_name));
            removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, prevAppName);
            removeIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"); 
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(removeIntent);
        }

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, HomeScreenShortCut);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"); 
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);


        //Make preference true
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled", true);
        editor.putString("phoneLanguage", currentLanguage);
        editor.putString("appName", getString(R.string.app_name));
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

I update it when the user change the language to reflect the name in new language.

Comment: Happy to help :) . May be you can upvote the answer as well :)